# Prove that if $xy>0$, then either $x>0\ \&\ y>0$ or $x<0\ \&\ y<0$

Tags: solution-verification

> **Theorem**: $$x\cdot y>0 \implies (x>0 \ and\ y>0)\ or\ (x<0\ and\ y<0)$$
> **Proof:**
>
> Suppose $x\cdot y>0$.
> If either $x$ or $y$ are $0$, then $x\cdot y=0$ which is a contradiction, so both $x$ and $y$ must be $\ne0$. This leaves four remaining possibilities for $x$ and $y$.
>
> 1. $x>0\ and \ y<0$
>
> Using the fact that multiplication by a negative number reverses the inequality sign (already proven as a theorem), $x>0\implies x\cdot y<0\cdot y \implies x\cdot y<0$ which is a contradiction.
>
> 2. $y>0\ and \ x<0$
>
> $y>0\implies y\cdot x<0\cdot x \implies y\cdot x<0$ which is a contradiction.
>
> $$\therefore\ x\cdot y>0 \implies (x>0 \ and\ y>0)\ or\ (x<0\ and\ y<0)$$

My question is if the above proof for the given proposition is valid. More specifically, is this argument sufficient or do I need to prove that both ($x>0,y>0$) and ($x<0,y<0$) do in fact result in $x\cdot y>0$?

Comment: Rather than proving it twice you can say "without loss of generality take $x  > 0, y<0$. You shouldn't have to prove $x> 0, y > 0 \implies xy >0$ since it's typically given as an axiom. You'll need to show $x< 0, y <0 \implies xy > 0$ though.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Wouldn't a proof of $x<0,y<0\implies xy>0$ be required for the converse of the statement of the theorem instead?

Comment: Yeah I mean the other direction so you're done.